# why my view page doesn't show out data in database mysql

Tags: php

I have successfully created log in and log out page..when the user success to log in using their username and password they will go to the view page but unfortunately the view page doesn't show out data in database mysql and also no error come out on that coding..

This is my viewpage.php

```
<html>    
<?php
include("authenticationStaff.php");
include ("dbase.php");
?>
<body>
 <table width="869" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
       <td width="645" height="50" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Welcome ,&nbsp; You log in as &nbsp; &nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_STAFF_NAME'];?> 
       <td width="377" align="right" valign="middle"><strong><a href="logout.html" title="Logout">Log Out</a></strong></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </center>
   <?php
   $query= "SELECT s.staff_id,s.staff_name,i.project_name,i.location,i.cost,i.pic,i.detail,i.file_name,i.file_type,i.file_size,i.file_content,i.staff_id
FROM staff s
JOIN inter1 i 
on(s.staff_id = i.staff_id)
WHERE i.staff_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_ID']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" class="horizon_divider"><p>&nbsp;</p>

       </td><td width="750" valign="top"><div align="center">
         <h3>DATA</h3>
         <table width="836" border="2" align="center" style= "background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <th width="142">PROJECT NAME</th>
      <th width="114">LOCATON</th>
      <th width="94">COST</th>
      <th width="151">PERSON IN CHARGE</th>
      <th width="187">DETAIL</th>
      <th width="187">ATTACHMENT</th>
      <th width="88">ACTION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
            echo
            "<tr>
              <td>{$row['project_name']}</td>
              <td>{$row['location']}</td>
              <td>{$row['cost']}</td>
              <td>{$row['pic']}</td> 
              <td>{$row['detail']}</td> 
              <td></td> 

             <td><a href='editStaff.php?id={$row ['staff_id']}'>ADD NEW RECORD</a>||<a href='deleteStaff.php?id={$row ['staff_id']}'>DELETE</a></td> </tr> ";

          }
        ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
        </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

Can someone see where I am going wrong?if you need any more info then please let me know. thanks.

Comment: How is `$_SESSION['SESS_ID']` defined?

Comment: i define $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] in sessonHandler.php

Comment: Add `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` to see all errors.

Comment: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);??? where should I add this code?? after $query/before $query??